# Splitcontainer switch horizontal vertical runtime same size and center Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form with a splitcontainer.At runtime the user can switch between vertical and orizontal,when switching the size of the panel are not the same and one side you can barely see anything unless a user makes it bigger.

What properties can I set to make both panels to be the same size when they switch between orientation?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change the Orientation try this:

```
splitContainer1.SplitterDistance =
   (splitContainer1.Orientation == Orientation.Vertical? 
    splitContainer1.Width : splitContainer1.Height) / 2;
```

or of course simply, when setting to horizontal:

```
splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = splitContainer1.Height / 2;
```

..and when setting to vertical:

```
splitContainer1.SplitterDistance = splitContainer1.Width / 2;
```

..respectively.

(Note I have now erred **twice** on the Orientation, sigh. I guess it's just not as simple as it looks ;-))

Comment: Hi there ,sorry for late reply,It does work for vertical (changed Horizontal to vertical but does not work for horizontal

Comment: So sorry - I got (pun intended) - disoriented. See the corrected solution!